# Run program, save data in text file and read it back

Tags: c++, ubuntu, text-files

For some reason (unknown to me as a C++ beginner) my program is having troubles on outputting the data to a text file. Long story short:

I am working on a Game of Life program, where one of the menu options must show the game statistics. The program should run, send the data to a text file and later on, when I call it back on the menu, I would get the statistcs on the screen.

The statistics is nothing more than a text file showing the 'generation number' and 'number of alive cells'. It would be saved on the text file as, for example: (without the points)

1. 30
2. 41
3. 49
4. 52

The idea is, as above, starting at generation 1 but my program starts at generation 909. Big question: why?

909. 41
910. 49
911. 52

The rest of the program, including the other menu options, works really fine with no warnings.
I use CodeBlocks + Ubuntu.

Any help is really appreciated!

```
(...)

void world::statistics(){

int statsmenuchoice();
int alivecells;
int generation();
int i,j;
void displayItems(int x);
void getItems();

// write to file
ofstream worldFile;
   worldFile.open("stats.txt");

    for (int generation; generation < MAX; generation++){
        one();
        alivecells = 0;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<MAX; j++) {

            if (population[i][j]) alivecells++;}}{
      worldFile << generation << ' ' << alivecells << ' ' << endl;
            }
       } 

   worldFile.close();

// read from file and print on screen
    int statsmenuoption;
    printf("\033[0m\033[2J\033[H"); // empty screen in terminal
    statsmenuoption = statsmenuchoice();

    while(statsmenuoption != 2){ // return to menu
        switch(statsmenuoption){
        case 1:
            displayItems(1); break;
        } 
            statsmenuoption = statsmenuchoice();
    } 
    }


// statistics (sub)menu function
int statsmenuchoice(){
    int choice;

    cout << endl << " Choose 1 for Statistics or 2 for mainmenu: " << endl;
    cout << endl << " 1 :: show statistics" << endl;
    cout << " 2 :: back to (main)menu" << endl << endl;

    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

// display items function
void displayItems(int x){

    ifstream worldFile("stats.txt");
    int generation;
    int alivecells;
    printf("\033[0m\033[2J\033[H");
    if(x==1){
        while(alivecells >> generation >> alivecells){
                if(alivecells>0){
            cout << generation << ' ' << alivecells << ' ' << endl;
                } 
        } 
    } 

} // world::statistics

(...)
```

Comment: This line seems to be unneeded, please remove it: `int generation();`.

Comment: Have you compiled your program with warnings enabled (`g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror`), and have you fixed all warnings before asking your question on StackOverflow? If not, please do so, because maybe the compiler already tells you what to do, so you don't have to ask. If you don't know what a specific warning means and how to fix it, ask that as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `= 0`, so the line becomes:

```
for (int generation = 0; generation < MAX; generation++){
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help. Since yesterday I've been searching for it. You made my day!

Comment: If my answer helped you to fix the problem, then please click on the green tick to the left from the answer to accept it.